# Samsung Recovery Solution - create a custom recovery partition

Tags: recovery-partition

I've got a Samsung notebook with Samsung Recovery Solution installed. It can create a recovery images for later system restore.

The notebook has a service (factory) hidden partition, which can be used to do a system restore (<kbd>F4</kbd> during boot). I would like to replace factory image on this partition with my custom one I have create with Samsung Recovery Solution - I chose "Complete Restore".

The restore image format should be the same, but the Samsung Recovery created 4 files - `.w01`, `.w02`, `.wcl` and `.woo` - the latest is just:

```
[WinClon]
ELAPSED=1351
```

and when I looked into the hidden partition there are just Windows-like folders in Restore/Files.

Is it possible to replace the factory recovery image for to be able to have a simple <kbd>F4</kbd> custom recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end I have found a thread that has all this covered: https://www.sammymobile.com/forum/topic/samsung-recovery-solution-iii-the-recovery-partition/

Long story short:

1. rename your image restore files into: "init.*" (keep their former extension)
2. boot into Samsung Recovery
3. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to enter system admin tools
4. when asked for password enter "secos"
5. go to Image->Import and select your init files to import them into your hidden recovery partition

Comment: did you get to actualy do this and does it work as intended? I am curious as I may try this as well with a new version of Windows (7 Ultimate) vs the XP home that is currently in the partition.

Comment: Yes I did, it was quite easy to do with the information on given link or just those 5 bullets I wrote about it.

Comment: Looks like the URL has changed to https://www.sammymobile.com/forum/topic/samsung-recovery-solution-iii-the-recovery-partition/ (the above URL tried to redirect me, but the ampersand in the thread title caused problems)

Comment: I have fixed the broken link.

Answer (score -2):

## Before Proceeding Further

1. BACKUP YOUR HARD DISK IMAGES!!! DO NOT DELETE YOUR RECOVERY PARTITION UNTIL YOU HAVE MADE A DVD BACKUP!!! This cannot be stressed any further. It is wise to obtain copies of two backup images - one from your current hard disk, and extract the 'initial' image from the recovery partition itself. The latter can be done with a disk partitioning tool e.g. Easus Partition Manager where you copy the recovery partition to another visible one (same size or larger), and copy the image files init.wcl and init.woo.
2. USE SRS TO CREATE A RECOVERY DISC DVD. If you happen to corrupt or delete the recovery partition for any reason, this disc WILL re-create the recovery partition.
3. Note the Recovery Disc provided by Samsung is NOT the same as a SRS-created recovery disc. It is merely a customized (Samsung branded) Windows XP installation disc which installs Windows XP without any Samsung drivers e.g. for network, sound, touchpad etc. IT DOES NOT re-create the recovery partition.